# Java RegEx lookbehind construction

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

Need a little help to construct a regular expression for this scenario:

Contents:

```
<b>IfThisIsPresent:</b>
<span style="font-family:Arial">
<button type='submit'>
<span class="button-gradient">
<span class="button-test">
Look: NeedToExtractThat
</span>
```

So:
if string `IfThisIsPresent:` is in my string, I should extract what is right after `Look:` string.

I developed the following RegEx, but it's not working:

```
((?<=IfThisIsPresent:)Look:(.*))
```

I know Java Pattern class doesn't support if then else. So I'm using lookbehind to check if `IfThisIsPresent` exists, then extract what is after `Look:`.

Could someone help?

Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
(?s)(?<=IfThisIsPresent:.{0,1000}Look:).*
```

it matched for me:

```
NeedToExtractThat </span>
```

---

If you also want to get rid of following tags like `</span>` then you could use this regex:

```
(?s)(?<=IfThisIsPresent:.{0,1000}Look:)[^<]*
```

which matches:

```
NeedToExtractThat
```

see demo here: http://fiddle.re/8ez1h (click java button)

Comment: Just to complicate a bit more: what is it's the opposite? I mean, I want to extract what follows `IfThisIsPresent` if the `Look:` is present? The problem here is that I'd have to search for the `Look:` first, which is at the end of the string, and then come back to the beginning to search for the `IfThisIsPresent` and get the group. Can you give me a light? I believe I'd use lookahead instead of lookbehind, but no lucky with my tests.. :/. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've gone this far: `(?s).(?=.*Look:)IfThisIsPresent:(.*)[^<]` but it's not stopping at `<` using the expression `[^<]`

Comment: I think I got it: `(?s).(?=.*Look:)IfThisIsPresent:(.*?[^<]*)`

Comment: For the other way round this should work: `(?s)(?=.*Look:)IfThisIsPresent:[^<]*` Is your issue resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick I believe:

```
(?=.*IfThisIsPresent:).*?Look:(.*)
```

Comment: Will try, thanks. Any idea why `?<=` is not working? I would like to understand why my regex is not working :/

Comment: `(?<=IfThisIsPresent:).*?Look:(.*)` should also work. You need to allow for characters before "Look:".